# Error: Invalid or corrupted PDF file Firefox

Tags: javascript, pdf, firefox, file-upload

I am trying to upload a PDF file and once done uploading, I am trying to show that PDF file in an IFrame with the stream content I have with me in scope. Same code works if I upload an image file but throws below error for PDF upload in Firefox.

### Error

```
Invalid or corrupted PDF file.
PDF.js v1.9.583 (build: d7b37ae7)
Message: Invalid PDF structure
viewer.js:1359:7
Error: Invalid or corrupted PDF file.
```

### HTML

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />

<iframe id="uploadedFileIframe" title="PDF in an i-Frame" src=""  scrolling="auto" height="400" width="400" />
```

### CSS

```
  .thumb {
    height: 75px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
  }
```

### JavaScript

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      // Only process image files.
      if (!f.type.match('pdf.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      // Closure to capture the file information.
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          // Render thumbnail.

          var enc = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( e.target.result)))
          document.getElementById('uploadedFileIframe').setAttribute('src','data:application/pdf;base64,'+ enc);
        };
      })(f);

      // Read in the image file as a data URL.
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've overengineered the solution a little bit

```
document.getElementById('uploadedFileIframe').src = reader.result;
```

should work if you place it instead of

```
var enc = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent( e.target.result)))   
document.getElementById('uploadedFileIframe').setAttribute('src','data:application/pdf;base64,'+ enc);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kc8sdas5/

Answer (score 0):

You are accepting multiple files to be selected and you are always replacing the same iframe with a new source. You don't create a new iframe for each file. Also you don't have to read the file as a base64 string, it's pointless and also a bad for performances and memory. You could instead use the [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) instead, which is syncron, so you can get rid of your closure

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var previews = document.querySelector('#previews');
    var iframe;
    var URL = window.URL || webkitURL;
    
    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      // Only process pdf files.
      if (!f.type.match('pdf.*')) {
        continue;
      }

      iframe = document.createElement('iframe')
      iframe.title = "PDF in an i-Frame";
      iframe.scrolling = "auto";
      iframe.width = iframe.hight = 400;
      iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL(f);

      previews.appendChild(iframe);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />

<div id="previews"></div>
```